# Help with naming my admin related controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, naming-conventions, controllers

I can't come up with a nice name for my admin related controllers.

I have a UserController that is used for the site (non-admin related actions).  Now I created an ADMIN section that has the following url format:

www.example.com/admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}

My controller folder is layed out like:

/controllers/
/controllers/admin/admincontroller
/controllers/usercontroller

I need to make a controller for editing/deleting/listing users to perform admin related actions on them.

I will place this controller in my /controllers/admin/ folder just to keep them seperate.

**What should I name this controller?**

I don't want to do AdminUserController

As it just looks silly, any help!?

Answer (score 2):

You could put them in an YourProject.Controllers.Admin namespace.

Alternatively if it is just for "url" purposes, you could create specific routes for these controllers, i.e.

```
routes.MapRoute("/admin/users/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "AdminUser" });
```

Answer (score 1):

AdminActionsController?

Is there a reason you don't want them inside your AdminController?  All of these actions seem to fall under this category.

EDIT: What about EditController then?

Comment: I don't like actions that have 2 words in them, like www.example.com/admin/edituser/342

Comment: Why would the actions have to be two words inside your controller?  If you didn't have an admin folder, then your default URLs could be /admin/edit/{userId} or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

UserManagementController or perhaps ManageUserController or something else along those lines.

www.example.com/admin/UserManagement/{action}/{id}
www.example.com/admin/ManageUser/{action}/{id}